# How can I replace 'No.' in Biblatex with № in when printing the 'number' field?

Tags: biblatex

I am using `biblatex` and would like the `number` field in `@report` to print in the bibliography as `№` (the numero sign) rather than `No.`

Here is an example, non-working, which prints No. rather than №:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=oxnotes-ibid,backend=biber,issuestyle=colon,usenametitles=true,dashed=true,]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}

    @report{FacchiniTesta2016,
  author      = {Facchini, Giovanni and Testa, Cecilia},
  title       = {Corruption and Bicameral Reforms},
  year        = {2016},
  series      = {Discussion Papers},
  number      = {11281},
  institution = {Centre for Economic Policy Research},
  address     = {London},
  url         = {https://cepr.org/active/publications/discussion_papers/dp.php?dpno=11281},
}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}
    This is a sentence.\autocites{FacchiniTesta2016}
    
    \printbibliography
    
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se and thanks for posting a minimal document!

Comment: Depending on your engine you can either say `\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  number = {№},
}` (with the Unicode engines) or `\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  number = {\textnumero},
}` (with pdfLaTeX, on older systems additionally with `\usepackage{textcomp}`).